# Why did Ezra stay behind?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the series finale of Star Wars Rebels, we see Ezra stay behind on Thrawn's Star Destroyer as the Pergil carry the ship into Hyperspace.

My question is, why exactly did he stay behind? All he seemed to do was Force-hold Thrawn at the bridge, although Thrawn probably wouldn't have been able to get away from the tentacles anyway.

Answer (score 6):

As we last saw, Ezra just forced the doors shut, and a group of stormtroopers out of the bridge.

What that means is: Thrawn still had troops left who could have freed him from the tentacles, and if someone was able to find a way to return... then HIM. Thus, Ezra needed to stay behind to make sure Thrawn wouldn't get that chance, AND at the same time make sure he couldn't return to exact revenge on Lothal.

Comment: This is essentially the right answer. Ezra enters the leviathans’ hyperspace jump actually doing two things: 1) keeping Thrawn immobilized; 2) keeping blast doors shut. Ezra could have given up one or both but at risk to his plan. So to increase plan’s success, he saw each through to the end.

Answer (score 0):

the same reason Kanaan Stayed on the tanker to allow the others to get away & complete the mission. It was the only way to make sure thrawn & the mission was successful. he saw it as his destiny he says so in his video to the team that he saw a lot of paths & this wasnt the one he wanted but it was the only one he saw that would complete the goal for the rebels while freeing his home planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain why Ezra staying behind was necessary for the mission to succeed?